# Load COM Library into Qt

Tags: c++, qt, skype4com

I'm able to load the Skype COM library (Skype4COM.dll) into a C++ visual studio project, and here is the code to do so:

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Skype\Skype4COM.dll" 
using namespace SKYPE4COMLib;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    ISkypePtr pSkype(__uuidof(Skype));
    pSkype->Attach(6, VARIANT_TRUE);

    IChatMessage *message;
    message = pSkype->SendMessage(_bstr_t(L"user_name"), _bstr_t(L"Hello"));
    printf("%s sent message", (char *)message->FromHandle);

    pSkype = NULL;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to load a COM library into Qt? Because it would be nice to use Skype's library to make a GUI in C++.

Comment: Qt is simply a C++ framework. The code above will work from a Qt project, too. You can also use [ActiveQt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-index.html) to do it using Qt itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to load *and use* a COM library into Qt?

1. Remove all the routine COM (un)initialization e.g. CoInitialize/CoUnitialize.
2. Look at [Qutlook Example (ActiveQt)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-activeqt-qutlook-example.html).
3. Implement your own COM interface import with [TYPELIBS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-dumpcpp.html) statement in YourProject.pro file or with `dumpcpp` tool.

Mind that Qt own dumpcpp utility that provides the convenience of COM objects wrapped to own Qt QAxObject/QAxWidget classes is not very reliable and its import differs between Qt framework version. I had to rewrite quite a few lines of code while converting the project from Qt 5.3 to Qt 5.5 for instance. I also mix Qt and ATL techniques.

Should you have more specific question(s) we can probably come up with answers based on experience.